# Type III factor examples?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

How to prove the crossed product of $G$ and von Neumann algebra $M$, where $G$ is locally compact group acting on $M$ via free ergodic action and $M$ is type $II_{\infty}$ factor, is type $III$ factor, how to see it does not have finite projecions rather showing lack of trace via non trivial modular group??

Comment: See Chapter XII, in particular,Theorem XII.1.1 in Takesaki's Theory of Operator Algebras.